# "Cannot use local variable 'csv' before it is declared

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

```
List<Zip> zipCodes = new List<Zip>();
void WriteToCsv(List<Zip> zipCodes)
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter("CurrentData.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        csv.WriteRecords(zipCodes);
    }
}
```

The csv.WriteRecords function is what is giving me the error. Am I not declaring it just above that?

Comment: Please show all of your code.

Comment: @DSander sorry, I was fighting with stack overflow. Is this better?

Answer (score 2):

missing a closing bracket **)** at the end of csv using block

like so:

```
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csv.WriteRecords(zipCodes);
}
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you! I feel so dumb for not realizing that.

Answer (score 0):

`using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

You're missing a ')'